# Intellij disable local history for specific files

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to disable the local history in Intellij, but only for the files from `src/test/`.

I can disable history only for these files, and to keep for the rest?

Or to specify for which folder to have history and automatically to not save for the others.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable local history for a specific files you need to exclude the folder in "Ignored Files and Folders" under Preferences | Editor | File Types